# Python - For Loop fails if only one item. 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following code that runs if Rank_Dict is able to be assigned.  The issue is that if Rank_Dict looks like example A and has two sets of values it loops fine but if Rank_Dict only has one pair of values like example B then I get an error.  Can you not loop over the result set that could only contain one value?

Error:

```
File "product.py", line 116, in <module>
ProductCategoryId=ranking['ProductCategoryId']['value']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Code:

```
try: 
   Rank_Dict=products_as_dict['Product']['SalesRankings']['SalesRank']
except:
  print("Didn't find Product/SalesRankings/SalesRank")
else:
  for ranking in Rank_Dict:
    ProductCategoryId=ranking['ProductCategoryId']['value']
    Rank=ranking['Rank']['value']
```

Data Example A - loops fine

```
[{'ProductCategoryId': {'value': 'home_improvement_display_on_website'}, 'Rank': {'value': '1335712'}},
{'ProductCategoryId': {'value': '17416540011'}, 'Rank': {'value': '2593'}}]
```

Example B - fails to loop

```
{'ProductCategoryId': {'value': 'home_improvement_display_on_website'}, 'Rank': {'value': '55928'}}
```

Comment: Convert it to array if there is one item, if Len(Rank_Dict) is 1

Comment: @arunp9294 not a good approach, you can have a `dict` with `len()` 1 and a `list` with `len()` 1. Still ambiguous :)

Comment: The first question to ask is where this data comes from. If it's generated by code you've written, or parsed via JSON from a service written by the guy who sits across from you at work, etc., the simplest thing to do is to fix the data so it's always a list of dicts instead of sometimes a dict and sometimes a list of dicts.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that this

```
[{'ProductCategoryId': {'value': 'home_improvement_display_on_website'}, 'Rank': {'value': '1335712'}},
 {'ProductCategoryId': {'value': '17416540011'}, 'Rank': {'value': '2593'}}]
```

is a `list` (filled with objects that happen to be dictionaries)

and this

```
{'ProductCategoryId': {'value': 'home_improvement_display_on_website'}, 'Rank': {'value': '55928'}}
```

is a dictionary.

So you are comparing the behavior of looping through two different `type`s of objects. Clearly there is room for errors..

There are several ways to address this problem. One of them is to *only loop if you have list*, otherwise just work directly with the object. In code,

```
import collections #Thanks @abarnet
try: 
   Rank_Dict=products_as_dict['Product']['SalesRankings']['SalesRank']
except:
  print("Didn't find Product/SalesRankings/SalesRank")
else:
  if isinstance(Rank_Dict, collections.abc.Sequence):
    for ranking in Rank_Dict:
      ProductCategoryId=ranking['ProductCategoryId']['value']
      Rank=ranking['Rank']['value']  
  else:
      ProductCategoryId= Rank_Dict['ProductCategoryId']['value']
      Rank= Rank_Dict['Rank']['value']
```

Comment: Unless this data is coming from, say, JSON, so we know `list` and `dict` are the only possible types, I'd use `collections.abc.Sequence` rather than `list` here.